# Why is vibrate API not available with ServiceWorker WorkerNavigator

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, service-worker, vibration

Can someone please confirm that the Navigator.Vibrate() API is not surfaced on the WorkerNavigator object? If not, does anyone have any ideas why not?

Comment: There's no why. Just deal with it.

Comment: Indeed. "There's no why; it's just our policy" - W3C/IETF

Answer (score 2):

In general, APIs have to be specifically opted-in to service workers, since they open up "interesting" security and privacy issues.

In the specific case of the Vibration API, it was developed before service worker was anywhere as ready as it currently is, but even so, it was restricted to pages that are in active use, to avoid abuse: https://www.w3.org/TR/vibration/

That being said, if you have an interesting use case for vibration in service workers, it would probably be useful to document it either in https://github.com/w3c/vibration or on https://discourse.wicg.io/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mimmo.    Which is the next API to be "opted-in"? As far as use-case goes: - The vibration sequence is sufficient to convey the message details without need for foregrounding or notifications.

Comment: WRT https://github.com/w3c/wake-lock/issues/50 I presume it would be inappropriate to attempt to hold a vibration lock across more than a single sequence. IOW such a lock does not need to be accessible to Javascript as the atomicity of the operation is controlled by the vibration API. ->Obtain lock--> transmit vibration sequence beginning to end --> release lock